# Version compatibility between ElasticSearch and Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I found it very confusing which version of Kibana to use for my ElasticSearch version (2.4 for example). Is there any chart or table summarizing the version compatibility between ElasticSearch and Kibana.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes there is!**

You can find all the data regrading the ElasticSearch compatibility [here](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_compatibility).
You can find Kibana capability under "*Product Compatibility*" and scroll down to "*Supported Kibana Versions*".