# Elasticsearch 8.x is compatible with spring-data-elasticsearch 3.0.5

Tags: java, elasticsearch, primavera

I would like to know if Elasticsearch 8.x is compatible with spring-data-elasticsearch 3.0.5, since I am working on an application with spring boot 2.0.0.release which cannot be migrated. but they asked me to migrate to the mentioned version of elasticsearch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Version compatibility between ElasticSearch and Kibana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40826283/version-compatibility-between-elasticsearch-and-kibana)

Answer (score 0):

The [official Spring Data ES documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions) provides the information. The maximum version for spring-data-elasticsearch 3.0.x is Elasticsearch 5.5 which is a very old and EOL version:

[image]